# ImageMagic not working on windows

Tags: windows, xampp, imagemagick, imagick, php-extension

As this blog suggested
[blog](http://refreshless.com/blog/imagick-pecl-imagemagick-windows/)

My Environment
windows 7 64-bit
xampp 5.6.12 32-bit

1. I installed ImageMagic for windows (32bit)
2. Setted environment path of ImageMagic and MAGICK_HOME variable
3. Downloaded the php_imagick.dll and pasted in C:\xampp\php\ext and the file name started with CORE_RL_* in C:\xampp\apache\bin

Now when apache starts it shows error

[the programme can't start because VCOMP110.DLL is missing from your computer. try reinstall program to fix this problem](http://screencast.com/t/IQgaQkcM)

I don't know why this error occurs.
Also I installed vcredist_x86.exe

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error message:

`The program can't start because VCOMP110.DLL is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

This means that you did not install the `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012`. You can download it from this page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: Yes I installed vcredist_x86.exe and checked vcomp110.dll in system32. still its giving me error. Sorry I didn't mentions this before

Comment: You might need a reboot after the installation. And which version of ImageMagick did you install?

Comment: I also did that :D, and I installed ImageMagick-6.9.2-5-Q16-x86-dll.exe

Comment: That version might not be compatible if your other software requires the VS2012 redistributable. Version 6.9.2-5 requires the VS2013 redistributable.

Comment: Does 64/32 bit version matter?

Comment: Still giving me the same error. Is there any permission issue? how I'm going to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
I am late here, but maybe it helps someone, you can check the Architecture using phpinfo(). 
ImageMagick + Imagick + PHP on XAMPP
Environment
Windows7
32bit OS
XAMPP v3.2.1
Step for install
Install Imagick (PHP Extention).
Install DLL of extension module.
Setting DLL.
1. Install ImageMagick (PHP Extention) under C:/
Install PHP Extention.
You must install correct version which corresponded to your OS version. i installed 32 bit version ImageMagick-6.9.1-10-Q16-x86-dll.exe.
Confirm extension_dir of phpinfo(); below is ok.
extention_dir C:/xampp/php/ext
2. Install DLL & Setting
2-1. Install PHP Extension
Install by PECL
!! Then confirm phpinfo(); you should select install.
Case of enabled > php_imagick.dll, TS
Case of disabled > php_imagick.dll, NTS

2-2. DLL file move into extension folder
php_imagick.dll in download folder move to C:/xampp/php/ext
2-3. CORE_RL_* move into Apache binary folder
CORE_RL_* file move into C:/xampp/apache/bin
2-4. Add extension to php.ini
You should write extension=php_imagick.dll on php.ini ( !! Write under [PECL] ).
3. Setting Environment
Add MAGICK_HOME to your environment PATH.
Try phpinfo();
4. convert image on CLI
>convert wizard: wizard.jpg
>convert wizard.jpg win:
But in this state, ImageMagick number of supported formats is 0 and ImageMagick supported formats is no value so you should do below.
All *_.dll file in C:/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/modules/coders copy to C:/xampp/apache/bin
All *_.dll file in C:/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/modules/filters copy to C:/xampp/apache/bin
All *_.dll file in C:/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/modules/coders copy to C:/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16
All *_.dll file in C:/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/modules/filters copy to C:/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16
Restart Apache

taken from:
http://hrt0kmt.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/05/27/170608
```